# Phonegap (build) large splashscreen makes Android app crash

Tags: crash, phonegap-build, splash-screen, phonegap

I set up splashscreens for my Phonegap app with the splashscreen Cordova plugin, built with "Phonegap Build".

In the splashscreen plugin docs they only mention pixel densities up to xhdpi, but recent devices go up to xxxhdpi.

So I added an xxxhdpi splashscreen image.

Now the app seems to crash on those devices on startup, and I think this is due to the large splashscreen.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>       at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw (DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
>       at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap (Canvas.java:1420)
>       at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw (BitmapDrawable.java:545)
>       at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw (ImageView.java:1286)
>       at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18319)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17297)
>       at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18081)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17292)
>       at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18081)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17292)
>       at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18081)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)
>       at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18322)
>       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw (DecorView.java:854)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17297)
>       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList (ThreadedRenderer.java:666)
>       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList (ThreadedRenderer.java:672)
>       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw (ThreadedRenderer.java:780)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:3112)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw (ViewRootImpl.java:2908)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2502)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1509)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7051)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:927)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:702)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:638)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:913)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6692)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1468)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1358)

In other questions I found the following suggestion:

```
Move your image in the (hi-res) drawable to drawable-xxhdpi
```

But using Phonegap Build, I don't see how I could do that. Is it not possible to have such large files? Should I remove the highest pixel densities? Is there an alternative?